# How do i enter values into a pointer function that is in a parameter of another function

Tags: c, parameters, function-pointers

For instance, if you have

```
void func(void (*location)(int *x, int *y), int (*occupied)(int a, int b))
```

How do I (from the main function) enter the values into this function?
Would i do this:

```
result = func((&c, &d), (3, 5));
```

I have looked everywhere and cannot find somewhere that explains how multiple pointer functions work in parameters. Please help!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Calling this function would be like `func( &loc_func, &occ_func );`  . If `func` needs to know what parameters to use when calling functions through those pointers then you will have to add more parameters to `func`

Comment: ... and please: first solve sudoku ...